# GeoTools error NumericConverterFactory and GeoServer 2.22.2 with Java 17

Tags: java, postgresql, postgis, geoserver, geotools

We've upgraded to GeoServer 2.22.2 (GeoTools 28.2, Java 17, Postgres 12.7 RDS, PostGIS 3.0.3, Tomcat 9.0.10). Everything runs well except that we get a GeoTools error for a WFS request with a Filter using FID:

[geotools.util] - Error applying the converter class org.geotools.data.util.NumericConverterFactory$NumericConverter on (GISDATA.BARRIERB_POLY.37,class java.lang.Integer)
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "GISDATA.BARRIERB_POLY"

Has anyone seen this error? I'm wondering if this could be an incompatibility with GeoServer 2.22.2 and Java 17 (we skipped from Java 8 to 17).

We tried the same WFS query on the same layer with and without the Filter.  Without the Filter the request returns good data instead of the error.  Request:

```
<wfs:GetFeature
      outputFormat="csv"
      xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
      service="WFS"
      version="1.1.0"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
      <wfs:Query typeName="massgis:GISDATA.BARRIERB_POLY" srsName="EPSG:26986" xmlns:massgis="http://massgis.state.ma.us/featuretype">    
            <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
                  <ogc:FeatureId fid="GISDATA.BARRIERB_POLY.37"/><ogc:FeatureId fid="GISDATA.BARRIERB_POLY.38"/>
            </ogc:Filter>
      </wfs:Query>
      </wfs:GetFeature>
```

We plan to try to downgrade to Java 11 in NonProd, but wanted to gather some more info first before we spent the effort.

Comment: can you try this one (from the demo requests) <wfs:GetFeature service="WFS" version="1.1.0"
  xmlns:topp="http://www.openplans.org/topp"
  xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
  xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs
                      http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
  <wfs:Query typeName="topp:states">
    <ogc:Filter>
       <ogc:FeatureId fid="states.3"/>
    </ogc:Filter>
    </wfs:Query>
</wfs:GetFeature> - It might be to do with the capitals in the name

Comment: It turns out it was not a Java version issue but an issue with the "attribute customization" being enabled for a subset of layers. Turning this off fixes our issue for now.

Comment: please add this as an answer and accept it so people in the future can find the issue

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was not a Java version issue but an issue with the "attribute customization" being enabled for a subset of layers. Turning this off fixes our issue for now.